# Printar um Array em <li> linha por linha com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, array

Preciso colocar os valores do array dentro de uma lista (`li`), linha a linha, porém o resultado recebido traz valores em única linha.

```js
let x = [
    {
        y: 'Título 1',
        z: ['1' , '2']
    }
];

html = '';

for(let i of x){
    html+= '<h2>' + i.y + '</h2>';
    html+= '<li>' + i.z + '</li>';
  }

document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

O seu elemento `i.z` é um array, então se quer que cada item dele fique separado em seu próprio `li`, faça outro `for` para percorrê-lo.

Não esqueça também de [colocar os `li`'s dentro de um `ul` ou `ol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li). E dê nomes melhores para as variáveis, pois `x`, `y` e `z` são genéricos demais (pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas [dar nomes melhores ajuda na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad) - como não tem muito contexto, dei uns nomes "menos genéricos mas ainda não-ideais"):

```js
let dados = [
    {
        title: 'Título 1',
        items: ['1' , '2']
    },
    {
        title: 'Título 2',
        items: ['a' , 'b', 'c']
    }
];

let html = '';
for (let element of dados){
    html += '<h2>' + element.title + '</h2><ul>';
    for (let item of element.items) {
        html += '<li>' + item + '</li>';
    }
    html += '</ul>';
}

document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

Você também poderia juntar os elementos usando `map` e `join`:

```js
let dados = [
    {
        title: 'Título 1',
        items: ['1' , '2']
    },
    {
        title: 'Título 2',
        items: ['a' , 'b', 'c']
    }
];

let html = '';
for (let element of dados){
    html += '<h2>' + element.title + '</h2><ul>';
    html += element.items.map(item => '<li>' + item + '</li>').join('');
    html += '</ul>';
}

document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Ou ainda, usando duas chamadas de `map` (uma para os elementos de `dados` e outra para os `li`'s):

```js
let html = dados
  .map((element) => {
        return '<h2>' + element.title + '</h2><ul>'
        + element.items.map(item => '<li>' + item + '</li>').join('')
        + '</ul>';
  })
  .join('');
```

Mas nesse caso eu acho um exagero. Cada chamada de `map` cria **outro** array, mas não acho necessário criar outro array só para juntá-lo depois, sendo que com *loops* simples você já consegue juntar tudo.

Answer (score 3):

Outra alternativa é utilizar o [*DOM HTML*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) que é uma representação estruturada do documento fornecendo métodos que permitem alterar a estrutura, estilo e conteúdo do mesmo.

No caso apenas foi feita uma iteração pela lista `x` e com o auxilio do método [`Document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) foram criados elementos DOM para os *HTML* `[<h2>][3]` e [`<ul>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul).
Cada `<h2>` tem sua propriedade [`Node.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) configurada com o valor da propriedade `y` do elemento iterado.
Para a propriedade `z` é feita uma nova iteração onde para cada item desse array é criado um elemento [`<li>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) cujo sua propriedade [`Node.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) configurada com o próprio valor do item da vez.

Com [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) os elementos criados são adicionados aos seus respectivos parentes que por sua vez são adicionados ao documento.

```js
let x = [{
    y: 'Título 1',
    z: ['1', '2']
  },
  {
    y: 'Título 2',
    z: ['3', '4']
  }
];

let expositor = document.getElementById("expositor");   //Obtém a referência ao div cujo vai exibir os dados renderizados. 

//Para cada elemento e da lista x...
for (let e of x) {
  let h2 = document.createElement("h2");                //...cria um novo elemento <h2>.
  let ul = document.createElement("ul");                //...cria um novo elemeto <ul>.
  h2.innerText = e.y;                                   //..seta o texto do <h2>.
  //...para cada elemento i de e.z...
  for (let i of e.z) {
    let li = document.createElement("li");              //...cria um <li>.
    li.innerText = i;                                   //...seta o texto do <li>
    ul.appendChild(li);                                 //...apensa o <li> no <ul>
  }
  expositor.appendChild(h2);                            //...apensa <h2> no <div> expositor
  expositor.appendChild(ul);                            //...apensa <ul> no <div> expositor
}
```

```html
<div id="expositor"></div>
```

Comment: Boa, eu ia sugerir isso também, mas fiquei com preguiça :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo Eu escrevi justamente porque você não tinha escrito e fiquei esperando e não veio....